# jQuery: Suppress `click` when `dblclick` is imminent?

Tags: jquery, events

Let's say I have a `<span>`. When you single-click this span, I want a `save()` function to fire. When you double-click the span, I want a `rename()` function to fire.

If you double-click the span, however, first the `click` event will fire, then the `dblclick` event. Since the `click` precedes `dblclick`, how can I tell `click` to not fire `save()` and instead defer to `dblclick` where `rename()` will be fired?

I can probably come up with a few workarounds, but is there any existing functionality in jQuery or previous (code) work that helps me with this already?

Comment: I've fought this same thing in the past, and I always end up using two single clicks instead of a double. I'm interested to see what comes of this.

Answer (score 7):

This looks helpful:
[single and double-click](https://gist.github.com/399624)

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick. I was trying to thing of a solution thats avoids the magic number in the Timeout (in their case 300ms), but I guess it's unavoidable. It's a shame though, since the double-click time differs on different systems.

Comment: How did you find this snippet, by the way?

Comment: In a comment from the jQuery documentation for dblClick()