# dblclick, click and overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal with a `click` event bound to it,
the modal has `position: absolute` and the highest `z-index` value.
The modal is floating above an element which has a `dblclick` event bound to it.

The issue is that when I double click the modal, the click event is fired and the modal is closed (that's fine), and the second click is actually on the element that the modal was floating above, and this element has `dblclick` event fired, which is obviously not wanted.

Simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4h2bx/1/

EDIT:

I want to emphasize the fact that the modal is not aware of the element that it is floating above, thus I cannot temper with this element's `dblclick` event

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764902/jquery-suppress-click-when-dblclick-is-imminent

Comment: Thanks for the references, please see the update in my question